# even after restarting apache/django static files served are older files even after they have been changed

Tags: javascript, css, django, apache, static

I have updated the css and js but still the files served by apache are older files. I have even checked on my sever. The files have been changed. There are no cache system present. I have also cleared my browser cache. Still the issue persists.

Comment: show your config file, etc if you want us to help diagnose further.

Comment: sorry can't show warath it some official work if you can help me by few assumptions. We are also using nginx as proxy server. I have also applied sendfile  off; in nginx conf file. as i investigated for the issue further.

Comment: thanks levi but i have already done that multiple times